# Storing global config variables in a Pyramid project

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm just getting started with Python's pyramid framework and am unsure where to set application variables and the best way to import them into my project. For example: database username/passwords, paths, thumbnail height/width, etc ...

Should I create a dedicated config.py file and import the variables into my functions? What should this look like?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a recipe in the cookbook for emulating the Django-style global settings file (for your convenience). However, the recommended way is to store these things in your INI file as deployment settings. Thus you could have one database username/password for development and one for production and it's as simple as having two INI files. All of the key/value pairs that you add to the `[app:...]` INI section for your Pyramid app are available at setup time and during request processing via a `settings` dictionary which is attached to the `registry`. This is accessible via `config.registry.settings` as well as `request.registry.settings`. The `settings` object is a copy of the `dict` that you passed into the `Configurator(settings=settings, ...)` within your `main` function.

For more information, see http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/startup.html as well as the tutorials within the Pyramid documentation which have examples of all of this.